# android auto slider using timer

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I create a slider with View Pager and use `Timer()` for the auto slide,

my code working fine, but slider changes are happening so fast and animation changes do not show.

how can I solve the problem?

Main Activity code:

```
viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            myAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
            viewPager.setPageTransformer(true,new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
            viewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);

            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 0,5000);
```

Timer Task code:

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0){
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                } else
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
        });

    }
}
```